# Get multiple fields based on ids in a string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two Tables : Table1 : **RolesTable** and Table2: **PrivilegeTable**.

**Sample Data in RolesTable**

```
Name |Description           |ModulePrivIds|FunctionPrivIds|Active
=================================================================
Role1|This is a Test Role   |1,2          |3,4            |1
Role2|This is another Role  |2,3          |1,3            |0
```

Note: **ModulePrivId** and **FunctionPrivIds** correspond to **Ids** in **PrivilegeTable**

Sample Data in **PrivilegeTable**

```
ID | Name |Description
========================
1  |Priv1 |This is Priv1
2  |Priv2 |This is Priv2
3  |Priv3 |This is Priv3
4  |Priv4 |This is Priv4
```

Now i want to display data in a grid for all the roles.So, Instead of ModulePrivId and FunctionPrivIds, I want to display the privilege names using Privilege Table.

Here is what I am trying but unable to achieve desired result.

```
var answer = (from r in database.RolesRepository.Get()
            join p in database.PrivilegesRepository.Get()
            on r.ModulePrivilegeIds equals p.Id.ToString() into ModuleWisePrivileges
            from p1 in ModuleWisePrivileges.DefaultIfEmpty()

            from r1 in database.RolesRepository.Get()
            join p01 in database.PrivilegesRepository.Get()
            on r1.FunctionPrivilegeIds equals p01.Id.ToString() into FunctionWisePrivileges
            from p2 in FunctionWisePrivileges.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new
            {
                Name = r.Name,
                Description = r.Description,
                ModuleWisePrivileges = ModuleWisePrivileges,
                FunctionWisePrivileges = FunctionWisePrivileges,
                Active = r.Active

            }).ToArray();

return answer;
```

I also tried the following but with no success.

```
var answer = (from r in database.RolesRepository.Get()
            join p in database.PrivilegesRepository.Get()
            on p.Id.ToList().Where(p => Id.Contains(r.ModulePrivilegeIds.ToString()) into ModuleWisePrivileges)
            from p1 in ModuleWisePrivileges.DefaultIfEmpty()

            from r1 in database.RolesRepository.Get()
            join p01 in database.PrivilegesRepository.Get()
            on r1.FunctionPrivilegeIds equals p01.Id.ToString() into FunctionWisePrivileges
            from p2 in FunctionWisePrivileges.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new
            {
                Name = r.Name,
                Description = r.Description,
                ModuleWisePrivileges = ModuleWisePrivileges,
                FunctionWisePrivileges = FunctionWisePrivileges,
                Active = r.Active

            }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why dont simply use `m:n` relationship between `Privilege` and `Role`? I think this is imposible without some sort of hacking (ie: sql view which will make it `m:n` for you... And then you have problem with insert) or loading whole table to your app and processing it localy (thats what are you trying to do in your code, which is kinda slow and headache)...

Comment: You know that this is a bad database layout? A good database layout would use a mapping tablele between RolesTable and PrivilegesTable. That way, you could use standard navigation properties.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth :    I suggested them to change the DB layout but they don't seem to want to change the DB. Any work around you can suggest?

Comment: @Jan'splite'Kondelík : Performance can be compromised here as the number of records in DB won't be huge. Still, is there a possible way out?

Comment: @gauravsachdeva As Daniel wrote in his answer ;)

Comment: Hi...Is there a way to add a where clause in the above select. I want the query to check whether the isDeleted flag is true or false and only fetch results for which isDeleted is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't fix the database, you are left with a multi step process:

1. Select the rows from `RolesTable`
2. Split the ID fields
3. Select the privileges from the database

Something like this:

```
var roles = database.RolesRepository.Get().ToArray();
var answers = roles.Select(r => new {
                Name = r.Name,
                Description = r.Description,
                ModuleWisePrivileges = r.ModulePrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                        .Select(x => database.PrivilegesRepository.Get(x))
                                        .ToArray(),
                FunctionWisePrivileges = r.FunctionPrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                          .Select(x => database.PrivilegesRepository
                                                               .Get(x))
                                          .ToArray(),
                Active = r.Active
            }
```

If your repository allows you to get multiple items at once, base on a list of IDs, performance can be improved.
If the list of privileges is small, it would be better to get them all into memory first:

```
var roles = database.RolesRepository.Get().ToArray();
var privileges = database.PrivilegesRepository.Get().ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
var answers = roles.Select(r => new {
                Name = r.Name,
                Description = r.Description,
                ModuleWisePrivileges = r.ModulePrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                        .Select(x => privileges[x])
                                        .ToArray(),
                FunctionWisePrivileges = r.FunctionPrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                          .Select(x => privileges[x])
                                          .ToArray(),
                Active = r.Active
            }
```

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I am getting an exception while trying to run this piece of code.

Comment: @gauravsachdeva: You need to give me the exception, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I am getting an exception while trying to run this piece of code. 
The exception says "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Comment: @gauravsachdeva: Well, that's another problem with your database structure: You don't have referential integrity. Nothing prevents you from adding a non-existant ID to the columns in the `RolesTables`. My code assumed that all privileges actually do exist. If that's not the case, you should ask a new question and reference this one.

Comment: Okay.. So what you are saying exactly is that if each role has a privilege attached to it, the above code would work?

Comment: @gauravsachdeva: What I am saying is that this code should work if each ID in your two columns `ModulePrivIds` and `FunctionPrivIds` actually has a counterpart in the `PrivilegeTable`-

Comment: Thank you Daniel.. I got this to work..  Marking your answer as the correct one..!!

Comment: Hi Daniel.. Just a quick question.. Is there a way to add a where clause in the above select. I want the query to check whether the isDeleted flag is true or false and only fetch results for which isDeleted is false.

Comment: @gauravsachdeva I don't see `isDeleted` in your tables.

Comment: They just added a new functionality in the roles table. But anyways, I figured out the way.. much thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this once, updated the above code with comma seperated values

```
var roles = database.RolesRepository.Get().ToArray();
var answers = roles.Select(r => new {
            Name = r.Name,
            Description = r.Description,
            ModuleWisePrivileges = string.Join(", ", (r.ModulePrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                    .Select(x => database.PrivilegesRepository.Get(x).FirstOrDefault())
                                    .ToArray()),
            FunctionWisePrivileges = string.Join(", ", (r.FunctionPrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                      .Select(x => database.PrivilegesRepository.Get(x).FirstOrDefault())
                                      .ToArray()),
            Active = r.Active
        }
```

updated the query as per your comment

```
 var roles = database.RolesRepository.Get().ToArray();
 var answers = roles.Where(a => a.isDeleted == false).Select(r => new {
        Name = r.Name,
        Description = r.Description,
        ModuleWisePrivileges = string.Join(", ", (r.ModulePrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                .Select(x => database.PrivilegesRepository.Get(x).FirstOrDefault())
                                .ToArray()),
        FunctionWisePrivileges = string.Join(", ", (r.FunctionPrivilegeIds.Split(',')
                                  .Select(x => database.PrivilegesRepository.Get(x).FirstOrDefault())
                                  .ToArray()),
        Active = r.Active
    }
```

Comment: Hi Suresh...Is there a way to add a where clause in the above select. I want the query to check whether the isDeleted flag is true or false and only fetch results for which isDeleted is false.

Comment: updated the query with where condition to get isDeleted is false